# Angular use service in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services

I have a service called `routing.service` which subscribes to routing event and when a parameter changes, it updates Translate service. As following in constructor:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
    if (val instanceof ActivationEnd ) {
        let myVal = val.snapshot.params.lang;
        this.currentLang = myVal;
        this.translate.use(myVal);
        this.translate.setDefaultLang(config.defaultLang);
    }
});
```

I have a shared module that is imported into the app module. In shared component everything works fine:

```
<div [innerHTML]="'HOME.TITLE' | translate"></div>
```

But in my lazy loaded modules not working. Even I can't access to `this.currentLang` that is inside `subscribe`. Any idea?

**Update:** Here is more detail about my code:

app.module:

```
imports:[
  CommonModule,
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  NgtUniversalModule,
  TransferHttpCacheModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  SharedModule
],
```

shared.module:

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  RouterModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useClass: TranslateUniversalLoader,
    }
  })
],
exports: [
  HeaderComponent,
  TranslateModule
]
```

lazy-loaded.module:

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  FormsModule,
  CustomersRoutingModule,
  SharedModule,
],
```

My app.component:

```
<!-- This is component of my shared.module and translation works fine here, but not in lazy loaded modules -->
<saz-header></saz-header> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I have a feeling you may have to import SharedModule into your other modules if you want to use your router.service. The lazy loaded modules wont be able to access it unless they import your SharedModule. Personally, I'd recommend moving your routing.service possibly into your AppModule. It makes more sense to have it there, or to a CoreModule

Comment: @N15M0_jk I have already imported SharedModule into my other lazy module. And what do you mean by `move your routing.service possibly into your AppModule`

Comment: Hmmm, that's unusual then. When I mentioned `move your routing.service possibly into your AppModule`, I assumed your routing.service isn't a provider in your AppModule. Would you kindly share your AppModule, SharedModule and lazy loaded module files so we can see how everything is imported/etc?

Comment: Just updated the post. Please see `Update` part. Thanks.

Comment: @N15M0_jk Yes, you are right. I didn't use `provider`.  Using `RoutingService` in app.module provider doesn't make sense, but using it in lazy-loaded.module works fine. But this time SharedModule can't access to service.

Comment: Ops, I have forgotten to inject the service in my SharedModule component. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Actually routing.service must be provided in SharedModule no AppModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got it working, but for sake of completion:

1) Double check in which module your service is provided. Generally, a routing service should always be accessible, and it makes sense to load with your AppModule, or depending on if you follow John Papa's suggested project structure, a CoreModule.

In your case, it might be logical to have the service imported in the AppRoutingModule.

2) If you do have a service that you'd like lazy loaded, it might be beneficial to include said service in an isolated, simple module that you can lazy load whenever you need it to (simply put, a small Module that just includes the few things you may or may not need)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I provide the service in AppModule, still in lazy-loaded module I can't access to service. I must provide it in SharedModule.

Comment: See this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no-for-root-72x3ht?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Cool, will check it out soon!

Comment: I think you didn't fork the project. The link is still the same.

Comment: Here you go, sorry about that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no-for-root-fz46kh

Comment: Thank you so much. And one more question. Should I import my external module (in this case TranslateModule) in AppModule or SharedModule? (I use TranslateService in my own routing.service)

Comment: My pleasure man, is your TranslateModule a lazy loaded module? If it is, you shouldnt need to import it in either, and it should only be referenced in your routing module (take a look at the app.routes.ts file from the Stackblitz from earlier, you'll see that the LazyModule is referenced in a route, and not imported anywhere). Does your TranslateModule have components you're routing to? or just a service that needs to be shared? If it's the latter, you could eager load it into your SharedModule or AppModule

Comment: Ohhh - translations would be system-wide, I recommend having that in your AppModule :)

Comment: So, when I use it in AppModule, My SharedModule component (Which I mentioned in the question: `<saz-header>`) gives me an error that translate pip is unknown. So I imported in SharedModule and set provider in SharedModule.

Comment: Hmmm, does it do that even if you import it in AppModule with: `TranslateModule.forRoot()` ? What I'll try do when I get a chance in 2 hours is modify the stackblitz we used earlier to get a working example for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190835/discussion-between-n15m0-jk-and-vahid-najafi).

Answer (score 0):

I had just forgotten to add the provider to my SharedModule as following:

```
providers: [
  RoutingService
]
```